# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has 2 roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

> I'm wondering how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has 2 roots of unity.

I was thinking something like:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then consider $(a+b\sqrt{-5})^n$. If we can show that $(a+b\sqrt{-5})^n$ is not real for any $n>0$ and $b\neq 0$ then we especially have that $(a+b\sqrt{-5})^n\neq 1$ and hence not a root of unity. Therefore we must conclude that $\pm 1$ is the only roots of unity. Maybe we need to use the binomial formula. Or well, I can't follow though with this argument, and maybe one needs a different technique.

(I know there is a general formula stating that for any field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $d<-4$ is no square, then the field only have 2 roots of unity. The proof of this theorem is more advanced, and my purpose with this question is rather to get familiar with the theory, on a more basic level, at first.)

Comment: This seems to wander a bit.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @abiessu What do you mean? My question is: How do you prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has 2 roots of unity?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_n) : \mathbb Q] = \varphi(n)$?  If so, you just need to figure out when we have $\varphi(n) = 2$ (not often) and then show that a few specific roots of unity aren't in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: @Ravi Fernando I am familiar with that fact. I guess $\phi(n)=2$ iff $n=2^c\cdot 3$ for $c\in \mathbb{N}$.  Ah, and this makes sense as I also know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$.  Hm, then I guess I need to check if $\zeta_{2^c3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. But for me it doesn't seem obvious how one can check that.

Comment: Oh, I am mistaken, $\phi(n)=2$ iff $n=3,4,6$

Comment: Ah, it makes sense! We have that $\zeta_3=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $\zeta_6=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, but as $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ then $\zeta_3,\zeta_6 \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Next I notice that $\zeta_4=i$. But if $i\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ then $\mathbb{Q}(i)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and as they both have index 2 we must get that $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ which is a contradiction as $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a UFD and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is not. Thanks a lot, @RaviFernando !

Comment: Fields are not UFDs since every non zero element is a unit. You need a different contradiction. Try showing that $\sqrt{-5}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @Rdrr Ah of course! And suppose we have that $\sqrt{-5}\notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$ as $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

Comment: Unfortunately, $i$ is also irrational, so that doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that first of all $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})}^\times=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]^\times$ is very small. If $a+b\sqrt{-5}\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]^\times$ then $N_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})/\mathbb Q}(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2=\pm1$, which only happens when $a=\pm1$ and $b=0$. Thus $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})}^\times=\{\pm1\}$.

**P.S.** The argument generalizes to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$ for $d>4$. When $d\equiv1,2\pmod 4$ the same exact argument applies. When $d\equiv3\pmod 4$, you have $N_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})}(a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}2)=a^2+ab+\frac{1+d}4b^2=\pm1$, which you can show only happens when $a=\pm1$ and $b=0$.

Comment: I follow your argument, but you found the units of $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and not the roots of unity of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$? Or do we have a connection between the units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and the roots of unity of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: Note that if $\epsilon^n=1$ for $\epsilon\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, then in particular $\epsilon$ is a root of the monic integer polynomial $x^n-1$, so must be integral.

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is that all roots of unity of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is especially an integral element over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, by definition of being integral. I guess I now need to conclude that all integral elements over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is in fact in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$? But is this always true?

Comment: I am saying all roots of unity in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ are in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})}$, the integral closure of $\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm all forgetting the definition of a ring of integers. Thanks @Kenta S !